# Using pattern matching to swap two elements in scala

Tags: scala

I would like to use the pattern matching to swap the first two elements of an array, my code as shown below:

```
>scala val arr = Array(1,2,3,4,5)

>arr match { case Array(a,b,rest @ _*) => Array(b,a,rest)
// Array(2,1,Vector(3,4,5))
```

However, the result should be `Array(2,1,3,4,5)`. How to revise it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not passing in `rest` as a varargs, which is done using `rest: _*` syntax. This tells the compiler to pass in the collection methods as varargs, it works with `Seq`.

```
val arr = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
arr match { case Array(a, b, rest @ _*) => Array(b, a +: rest: _*) }
```

There's an `Array.apply` method than takes a first element followed by a varargs, but there's none to pass in two elements and then varargs. Because of that, we need to prepend the second element to the `Seq` before passing the whole thing as varargs.

That's why we end up with `a +: rest: _*`. `+:` are invoked on the right hand side of the expression, so the method `+:` is defined on `Seq`, by convention Scala methods that end with `:` are right associative.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Whether `rest` equals to `Seq(3,4,5)`?

Comment: In addtion, I came out a workaroud `arr match { case Array(a,b,rest @ _*) => Array(b,a) ++ rest`